# How did sedeo, sedere supplant some forms of sum, esse in Vulgar Latin?

Tags: etymology, vulgar-latin, romance-languages

I had learned that the Romance languages' copulas come from Latin's *sum* verb obviously, but not all of its forms transferred over. Specifically the verb's present subjunctive forms seem to have been supplanted by a different verb, *sedeo* (I sit). Most Romance languages indeed get theirs from this verb:

- Spanish: sea
- Portuguese: seja
- French: sois (/swa/)
- Catalan: siga
- Italian: sia
- Sardinian: sia
- even Dalmatian: sai
- Romanian however has it's equivalent from Latin *fiam*, nevertheless all other notable Romance language gets theirs from Latin - ***sedeam***. 
  How did this occur and are there any attested examples that allude to this usage?

Comment: I assume that some forms must come from sedeo, but couldn't there be some contamination from the Latin subjunctive/optative forms of sum?  I had frankly assumed that "sia" and "sit" were related without really considering the issue.

Comment: Maybe, they were similar enough. Although that could be a reason for sedeo to supplant rather than be conflated or contaminated.